# Is it dangerous to pass pointers to a class with private *tors?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks, shared-ptr

If I have a class with private constructors and destructors, is it still dangerous to pass classic c-style pointers to instances (as in opposed to shared_ptr)? Are there any situations where memory could leak?
The lifetime of instances in my program is managed by a friend factory class exclusively (which also uses a private custom deleter to allow shared_ptr objects to be used internally by the manager class).

Comment: No, not at all. Why would it be dangerous to pass pointers around? That's what they're for. `shared_ptr` uses raw pointers internally anyway. And memory leaks have nothing to do with the private-ness or public-ness of constructors.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I was thinking that with public constructors clients would be able to instance the class, and passing normal pointers instead of shared_ptr could leak memory. With private constructors this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors do not matter at all if you already have the pointer. As for destructors — if you have a private one, you won't be able to `delete` is and, I believe, that will also prevent you from instantiating `shared_ptr` (as dandrestor pointed out — unless you provide a custom deleter, which you can use not only with `shared_ptr`).

All the limitations are imposed at compile-time, so if you fail to free your memory *because of privacy issues* you will be notified at compile-time.

Comment: you believe rigth: if the dtor is private the shared_ptr dtor, that has to call it, cannot be compiled.

Comment: Actually, you can compile shared_ptr if you pass a custom deleter function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202530/how-can-i-call-a-private-destructor-from-a-shared-ptr

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia, if we forget dandrestor's comment, I said "I believe" because I'm very cautious about making statements about the things I haven't tried — purely theoretical :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker what about run-time problems? My reasoning is that, since construction and destruction are handled separately, using normal pointers does not present a risk. What do you think?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker In my program, the custom deleter is a static private method of the manager class, so this restricts destruction to the manager class.

Comment: @dandrestor, only now I realized that you *are* the OP :))
Yes, using normal pointers does not present a risk related to privacy of construction and destruction. Not at runtime, at least. They also give benefit of being able to provide a pointer to the object allocated in stack for instance in member or friend functions :)

Comment: But… if the manager class is on friendly terms with the suspect, why would it need a private custom deleter?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Hah... because friendship does not propagate to its members. In my case, I use a vector of shared_ptrs and shared_ptr is not friends with the class in question.

Comment: Ah, right, what I was thinking of. I'm thinking… can't you befriend shared_ptr<yourthing>?

Comment: No, because shared_ptr is in itself a typedef or something else, anyway, it's a different class that actually ends up deleting the pointer. I reckon this is the exact reason for which they created the "deleter function" mechanism.